# How do I know the original file name for a renamed file from GitHub's post-receive hook?

Tags: github, github-api

Here is the situation:

1. I have a file in my repo, say `something/foo.md`.
2. I rename it with git, so that it is now `something/bar.md`.
3. I commit and then push
4. I get the post-receive payload from GitHub

The problem is: the commit shows `something/foo.md` as removed and `something/bar.md` as added, even though by viewing the commit on GitHub it show as renamed from `something/foo.md` to `something/bar.md`.

Does anyone know how I can get this information from a post-receive hook?

Comment: If the hash for `something/foo.md` and `something/bar.md` are identical, you know that they refer to the same content. I am under the impression that Git uses file similarity to determine whether a *remove/add* sequence is a *rename* or a *remove* followed by an *add*.